# Is this a threading issue? Binding results of backgroundWorker to WPF DataGrid causes hang

Tags: wpf, data-binding, backgroundworker, wpfdatagrid, defaultview

I cannot figure out why this is happening. Binding the DataGrid to a DataTable.DefaultView is causing the application to hang.  I want to display the contents of a CSV file that has been parsed and placed in a DataTable. This approach using the backgroundWorker succeeds in WinForms, and this WPF app is a simple port of a small import utility to learn WPF.  Here is the XAML

```
 <DataGrid  x:Name="detailGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="True"  />
```

and here's the code behind:

```
  private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error != null)
        {
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
        } 
        else
        {

            DataTable T = (e.Result as DataTable);
            // verified in immediate window that T.Rows.Count = 80106 at this point
            this.detailGrid.ItemsSource = T.DefaultView;

        }
```

It's my understanding that the RunWorkerCompleted event is raised on the UI thread, so there's no need to do Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action() ...  here.

Answer (score 0):

This was not a threading issue. The UI became unresponsive because no explicit **Height** had been set on the DataGrid.